# How to inject dependency in Servlet in Spring MVC 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

At present in my spring mvc based application i am implementing Servlets as well (this is a healthcheck servlet).
I am trying to inject dependency of a class in this servlet using @Autowire annotation but this class is not instantiating.

Please consider the below code.

```
@WebServlet(name = "myServlet", urlPatterns = "/app2")
public class HealthCheckController extends HealthCheckServlet{

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowire
      private MyService service;

    /**
     * method to check healthiness.
     *
     * @return true, if is healthy
     * @throws HealthCheckException the health check exception
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isHealthy() throws HealthCheckException {
        try {
            service.showDetails("12", false,null);
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Could you please suggest how can i provide dependency of MyService class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291894/failing-to-autowire-a-member-in-a-webservlet

Comment: Where did you provide myServlet? In dispachter-servlet or in application-context? If it is in disptcher-servlet, you have to add @Component to the webservlet and add <context:component-scan base-package="xxx" /> with the package of webservlet in disptcher servlet

Comment: myServlet is the name itself

Comment: you should provide the code for MyService class also and the beans configuration file if you are using XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Spring managed bean. Try adding `@Component` to the class declaration.

```
@Component
@WebServlet(name = "myServlet", urlPatterns = "/app2")
public class HealthCheckController extends HealthCheckServlet{
```

You can also try to refactor your class to be a Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("app2")
public class HealthCheckController extends HealthCheckServlet{
```

Another thing you can try is adding the servlet in the web.xml instead of using the `@WebServlet` annotation.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.HealthCheckController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `@WebServlet`? Maybe if you refactor this class to be a `@Controller` it should work.

Comment: My requirement is my HealthCheckServlet must be implemented. Now whether i do it by extending with other servlet or controller does not metter.

Comment: What kind of class is HealthCheckServlet? Does it implements HttpServlet, or something else?

Comment: ,Yes it is implementing  HttpServlet.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can try another workaround.

Comment: @Samir have you tried using `@ServletComponentScan`?

Answer (score 0):

Add '@Controller' as mentioned in the comments and update your URL mapping.  Also, what is calling isHealthy()?  Try adding your url mapping there.

```
@Controller
public class HealthCheckController extends HealthCheckServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowire
  private MyService service;

@RequestMapping("/app2/*")
public boolean isHealthy() throws HealthCheckException {
    try {
        service.showDetails("12", false,null);
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception  e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Adam,this works fine but i am getting 406 unsupported media type.I have used MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON on isHealthy().but no success.

Comment: Your question was about dependency injection.  If there is another issue you may need to research that and possibly post another question if you cannot find a solution to that new problem.